# Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Have an array called `categoryImages` that I'm trying to pass into a function, and get the following error:

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string'

```
const getLink = (
    groupCode: string,
    groupDisplayName: string,
    groupCount?: number,
    groupImage?: string
  )

const categoryImages = [
        attachmentImage,
        compactorImage,
        telehandlerImage,
        backhoeLoaderImage,
        excavatorImage,
        wheelLoaderImage,
        compactTrackLoaderImage,
        skidSteerLoaderImage,
      ];

} else if (Constants.isEnvironmentBFE) {
          count++;
          const newLink = getLink(
            // Grabbing API values
            group["group-code"],
            group["group-display-name"],
            group.count,
            // Load in local images
            categoryImages // <-- throws error here
          );
          categoryList[column].push(newLink);
          endColumnCheck(count);
        }
```

I basically want to output this array of images, into the DOM.

Comment: Doesn't that make sense? You are passing an array of string to a method which is expecting only string and not an array?

Comment: declare it as string[] if it is an array of strings? Or do not pass an array where it expects a string?

Comment: It's unlcear where this error is happening, but basically you're trying to set an array of strings where a string is expected.

Comment: Typescript is **not** Javascript. Don’t tag a question with both languages unless it actually applies to both. The React tag is also dubious and could probably be eliminated, as this question does not illustrate its involvement.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve said that the “getLink” function takes an argument “groupImage” which is a single image, But when you call the function you are giving it an array of images “categoryImages”.

You can:

- call “getLink” with categoryImages[0] instead of the whole array. Since the image is optional this will be ok even if the array is empty.
- loop through the array and call “getLink” separately for each element
- refactor “getLink” to accept an array of images